# DeviceId() shows me nullpointer?

Tags: android, telephony

i am developing an app in that i just need IMIE number of device...

I tried:

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imie = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

In Menifiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Let me tell, if that require any other things to do??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using emulator and running this app on emulator?..

Comment: Are you testing on emulator? On emulator it will give null pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it right, but according to the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html):

> We have seen a few instances of production phones for which the implementation is buggy and returns garbage, for example zeros or asterisks.

Also, it probably won't work on an emulator.

Comment: before one day it gives me "000000000" like that

Answer (score 0):

This is not the IMIE number for the device but if you just need an identifier for the device, you can also try `Build.SERIAL`.  Like `getDeviceId()` the value might not always be unique or available but it's another option to try when the first method fails.

Answer (score 0):

following may not work properly on emulator..

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String szImei = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Now sometimes its require to get the unique number from non-telephonic device (e.g Tablet) at that time we can create Pseudo-Unique ID, that works on all Android devices which gives unique number like IMIE. The ID computed in this way won't be unique: it is possible to find two devices with the same ID (based on the same hardware and rom image) but the chances in real world applications are negligible. For this purpose you can use the Build class:

```
String PUID = Build.BOARD.length()%10+ Build.BRAND.length()%10 +
            Build.CPU_ABI.length()%10 + Build.DEVICE.length()%10 +
            Build.DISPLAY.length()%10 + Build.HOST.length()%10 +
            Build.ID.length()%10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length()%10 +
            Build.MODEL.length()%10 + Build.PRODUCT.length()%10 +
            Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 +
            Build.USER.length()%10 ;
```

PUID will return 13 digits number  and we are adding two more in front (35) to have the same size ID like the IMEI (15 digits).

```
 PUID = "35" + PUID;
```

and great think is that we do not need to add READ_PHONE_STATE permission using above code.

For more help in generating unique number visit [pocket magic.](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1662)